# PhpStorm & XAMPP - I can not debug

Tags: php, xampp, phpstorm, xdebug

I spend several hours already and I don't know what's wrong. I can't debug. XAMPP is in 64 bit, PhpStorm also. I have checked "breaks at first line in php script" and break point is not hitting while debugging.

Logs:

[image]

Server configuration:

[image]

[image]

Php
[image]

[image]

Comment: THat version of XDEBUG looks a little old. Maybe upgrade to 2.8 for PHP 7.3

Comment: Ok, thanks! I will try,

Comment: 1) What is your IDE version? 2) What is the full path to that file (as seen in IDE)?